# How can I create an Active Admin table in a custom page and insert JSON data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, custom-pages

I'm trying to build a table of JSON data in a custom page in Active Admin. The JSON response is fairly deeply nested so I'm using a lot of loops. Here's as far as I've been able to get/some of what I've tried:

```
panel "Boxes" do   
  boxes.each do |box| #isolate each hash item in the array

    # table_for box.values do
      box.each do |key, value|
        if value.is_a?(Hash) #if value of a hash is a hash
          columns do
            value.each do |k, v| #iterate through the hash
              text_node "#{k}: #{v}"
            end
          end
        elsif value.is_a?(Array) #there's only one value that's an array & the key is "Products"
          columns do
            value.each do |products_array|
              columns do
                products_array.each do |k, v|
                  if v.is_a?(Hash)
                    v.each do |kk, vv|
                      if vv.is_a?(Hash)
                        vv.each do |kkk, vvv|
                          text_node "#{kkk}: #{vvv}, "
                        end
                      else
                        text_node "#{kk}: #{vv}, "
                      end
                    end
                  else
                    text_node "#{k}: #{v}, "
                  end
                end
              end
            end
          end 
        else
          # key.each do 
          #   column key
          # end
        end
      end
    # end
  end
```

I'm looking for general guidelines as to how to make a table in a custom Active Admin page as well as how to access/display deeply nested array/hash attributes. Thanks!

Comment: the var in "boxes.each" is my json response body

Answer (score 0):

Try a recursive helper to convert the JSON to the string you want:

```
def nested_hash_to_s(h)
  h.map { |k, v| v.is_a?(Hash) nested_hash_to_s(v) : "#{k}: #{v}" }.join(", ")
end
```

then your column simplifies to:

```
columns do
  text_node nested_hash_to_s(products_array)
end
```

There might be other issues, but that's a start.